# No name 'bigquery' in module 'google.cloud'

Tags: python, google-bigquery, navigator

I am using Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12, Python 3.6.4, and VS Code 1.48.2.

I have written the following code:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    QUERY = """
        SELECT provider_city, provider_state, drg_definition, average_total_payments, 
        average_medicare_payments
        FROM 'bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_charges_2015'
        WHERE provider_city = "GREAT FALLS" AND provider_state = "MT"
        ORDER BY provider_city ASC
        LIMIT 1000
        """
    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('MedicareProject-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json')
    query_job = client.query(QUERY)
    df = query_job.to_dataframe()
    print ("Records Returned: ", df.shape )
    print ()
    print ("First 3 Records")
    print (df.head(3))
```

The following code line gives an error: `from google.cloud import bigquery`

The error message is:

```
No name 'bigquery' in module 'google.cloud'
```

Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install BigQuery module:

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery
```

Document Link:
https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/

[image]

Comment: How do I do that in Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this. Is "New Terminal" in Anaconda Navigator or VS code?

Comment: Open Anaconda Navigator -> Click on base(root) > Click “Open Terminal”

Comment: Alternatively, you can open Jupiter Notebook and Click "Terminal". (I have added the snapshot in the code)

Comment: Thank you . I was able to do that in Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: Now I am getting this error in the above code: google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_char...' at [3:10]. Any ideas what might be wrong here?